# Tradingview pine script alertcondition on strategy.entry

Tags: pine-script

I have problem with `alertcondition` in strategy.

I want to have alert condition when I go LONG and exit LONG.

[alert signals like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTDOE.jpg)

I dont know how to write a script in strategy.

my script:

```
strategy.entry('LONG1', strategy.long, when=testPeriod() and jlong1 and jtest1 and jlong1_5min and jtest_rsi1)

alertcondition(condition=??????, title='LONG')

stopPer = input(1.0, title='Stop Loss %') / 100
takePer = input(1.0, title='Take Profit %') / 100
trail_inp = input(1.0, title='Trailing %') / 100


longStop = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stopPer)
longTake = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takePer)

trail_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - trail_inp)
trail_offset1 = int(close * trail_inp / syminfo.mintick)


if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit(id='Close Long1', stop=longStop, trail_price=longTake, 
trail_offset=trail_offset1)
alertcondition(condition=??????, title='exitLONG')
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need the `alertcondition()` function. Both `strategy.entry()` and `strategy.exit()` functions have the `alert_message` parameter which you can use.

More information [here](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000481368-strategy-alerts/) and [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Alerts.html).

Here is an example:

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long, alert_message="Going Long")

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short, alert_message="Going Short")
```

Comment: i solve the problem by includin comment in script and .........,"orderType": "{{strategy.order.action}}", "StrategyComment":"{{strategy.order.comment}}"....... in massage.